# Philippine national, UK resident, do I need a visa for holiday in Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, filipino-citizens, uk-residents

I am a Philippine citizen currently UK resident. I wanted to take a 1 week holiday in Spain. Will they allow me entry with my UK biometric residence permit + Philippine passport or do I need a visa?

Comment: No, the UK residence permit is not fungible for a British passport in Schengen and Pinoy need to get visas when they travel there. You will need a visa.

Comment: @GayotFow unless the residency is based on EU freedom of movement law.